# sybase update getting slower and slower

Tags: sql, database, linux, perl, sybase

I have a big text file about 4GB, and more than 8 million lines, I'm writing a perl script to read this file line by line, do some processing and update the info to sybase, i did this in a batch way,   1000 lines per batch for update commit, but here comes the problem, at first, a batch only costs 10 to 20 seconds, but with the processing goes, updating  a batch becomes slower and slower, a batch costs 3 to 4 min, I definitely have no idea why this is happening! Any body can help me analys this what may be the cause? Thanks in advance, on my knee...

Answer (score 0):

> > ==>I'm writing a perl script to read this file line by line, do some processing and update the info to sybase
> >
> > Please do entire processing at one go  mean process your source file at one go; Prepare data structure using hash, array as per requirement and then start inserting data into database.

Please keep below points in mind while inserting large data into database.

1- If each column data is not too large then you can insert entire data at one go also.( you may require good RAM not sure about size because it depend on dataset u need to process).

2- You should use execute_array of perl DBI so that you can insert data at one go.

3- If you have  not sufficient RAM to insert data at one go then please devide your data ( may be in 8 part, 1 million lines each time).

4- Also Make it sure that you are preparing the statement once. In every run you are just executing with new data set.

5- Set your auto_commit off.

A sample code to use execute_array of perl DBI. I have used this to insert around 10 million of data into mysql.

Please keep ur data in arrays like below in the form of array.
   @column1_data, @column2_data, @column3_data

```
 print $logfile_handle, "Total records to insert--".scalar(@column1_data);
    print $logfile_handle, "Inserting data into database";
    my $sth = $$dbh_ref->prepare("INSERT INTO $tablename (column1,column2,column3) VALUES (?,?,?)")
                or print ($logfile_handle, "ERROR- Couldn't prepare statement: " . $$dbh_ref->errsr) && exit;
    my $tuples = $sth->execute_array(
                { ArrayTupleStatus => \my @tuple_status },
                \@column1_data,
                \@column2_data,
                \@column3_data
                );

$$dbh_ref->do("commit");
    print ($logfile_handle,"Data Insertion Completed.");
    if ($tuples) {
        print ($logfile_handle,"Successfully inserted $tuples records\n");
    } else {
    ##print Error log or those linese which are not inserted
        my $status = $tuple_status[$tuple];
            $status = [0, "Skipped"] unless defined $status;
            next unless ref $status;
            print ($logfile_handle, "ERROR- Failed to insert (%s,%s,%s): %s\n",
                        $column1_data[$tuple], $column2_data[$tuple],$column3_data[$tuple], $status->[1]);
        }
    }
```